# What does ( (value_in_dictionary) modulo[%] (dictionary) ) does in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, modulo, string-interpolation

I want to understand what `value_in_dictionary % dictionary` does.

I tried

```
values = {
    'hello':'world',
    'hello2':'world2',
}
value = 'world'
print(value % values)
```

This prints

```
world
```

Comment: Like Mad Physicist answered, this example doesn't actually do anything. Where did you see this syntax used? Maybe we could provide more context. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: I was understanding a piece of code , where this was used. I was just providing an easy example , but gave a wrong example instead Xd. Thanks BTW .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For strings, modulo triggers [old style string interpolation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting). The right hand operand can be a scalar, tuple or dictionary.

The documentation reads as follows:

> When the right argument is a dictionary (or other mapping type), then the formats in the string *must* include a parenthesised mapping key into that dictionary inserted immediately after the `'%'` character. The mapping key selects the value to be formatted from the mapping. For example:
>
> ```
> >>> print('%(language)s has %(number)03d quote types.' %
> ...       {'language': "Python", "number": 2})
> Python has 002 quote types.
> ```

Your particular example has no formats in it, so nothing gets interpolated. Adding a valid interpolation key like `world = 'hello %(hello)'` or `world = 'hello %(hello2)'` would illustrate how it works. Attempting `world = 'hello %(hello3)'` would result in a `KeyError`.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that in the example in the question, the formatting doesn't actually do anything because the "format string" doesn't have any replacements to do. With `value = "foo %(hello)s bar"` it would.

Comment: @Blckknght. I was typing that just as you mentioned it :)

Comment: Thanks @MadPhysicist Got it now !

Comment: Sure Sir @MadPhysicist